# Conditional comment "gt ie 7" breaks chrome and firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, conditional-comments

I'm doing the old CSS conditional comments to block out a .css from being used when using IE 7 and below using:

`<!--[if gt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="some-styles.css" />
<![endif]-->`

However, this prevents this .css from being used in non IE browsers. This is the first time I've come across this.

I've seen the use of conditional comments targeting non IE browsers exclusively but surely there must be another way?

Comment: Does this surprise you? The above is simply a *comment* (only MSIE sees it as anything else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional comment should only be used to target IE browsers. I don't think any other browsers support this "feature".

I would suggest that you put all your styles into a main style that all browsers can see and then using the conditional statements for pre-IE 8 browsers to add/remove any style declarations that don't work on those browsers.

Comment: This is the thing I ended up doing.

Comment: @Dennis: Although you ended up not using conditional comments, this doesn't answer your question about the conditional comments.

Answer (score 2):

To make it visible for non-IE browsers, remove the comment delimiters `--`, as outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Like this:

```
<![if gt IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="some-styles.css" /> <![endif]>
```

Comment: That’s not valid HTML though, is it? (or is `[` a valid tag name character, in which case it’d work – but not in XHTML)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, it doesn't validate straight off, but browsers will just see it as an unknown tag and ignore it.

Comment: @Guffa There's also a syntax that validates. See [this blog post](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/valid_downlevelrevealed_conditional_comments/) as well as [my question/answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33132856/3345375) for more info.